# Does angular language service works with Nativescript?

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I've installed Angular Language Service on vs code but when i use with Nativescript it's complaining the following:

`[Angular]
'StackLayout' is not a known element:
1. If 'StackLayout' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.`

Am I missing something?

Comment: Follow step number 2. it will fix your problems, you will need to add the NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA to all of your ngModules

Comment: the element should be a component

Comment: StackLayout, is one of NativeScript built in components. Angular's language services doesnt' know about these components though. so by setting the NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA you are effectively telling angular to disregard the unknown element.